# UDP connection appearing multiple times in netstat command

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, udp, netstat

I ran the following command
[image]

I would like to ask

**why are the last 4 rows same? Is this the same connection or what?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you have more than one socket listening on the same port. This is not uncommon.

With the [SO_REUSEADDR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621(v=vs.85).aspx) option, multiple threads or processes can share a listening port.

This is often used as an easy way for an application to scale up a UDP service to use more than one thread or CPU core.  Let's imagine a service listening on UDP port 3702. And let's say for each incoming packet, some long blocking I/O operation has to be done. If the server application was single threaded, it would only be able to process 1 packet a time.

So instead, the server creates 4 threads (or 4 processes).  Each thread creates the socket, sets the SO_REUSEADDR option on the socket, binds to port 3702, and starts listening (`recvfrom`) for incoming packets.  When an incoming packet arrives, one of the threads blocked on a `recvfrom` call will be woken up and have a packet to process.  While that thread is processing the packet, the other threads are capable of receiving packets too in parallel.

Comment: What does it mean to have "more than one socket listening on the same port"? I mean how one socket ( ip, port pair) can listen to same port?

Comment: `recvfrom` is applicable to TCP as well?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it any better than I did. You have two or more *sockets* sharing a single UDP *port*.  When a packet arrives on the UDP port, one of the sockets will get the packet.

Comment: TCP is similar with some difference. You can have multiple TCP listening sockets sharing a port (but blocked on `accept` instead of `recvfrom`). It's a different threading model for scaling up and other facilities like epoll or IOCP are used.